# Page transition scripts

Tags: jquery, html

We are going to build a simple few pages html link. We want to have a page transition effect e.g fly in, fade etc on opening the clicked link. Is there any good sample codes to follow?

Answer (score 2):

Try these link, all using jquery -

[Link 1](http://devsnippets.com/article/10-transition-effects-the-art-of-showinghiding-content.html)

[Link 2](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/50-amazing-jquery-examples-part1.html)

[Link 3](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/advanced-jquery-effects/)

**NEW EDIT** --

For the link ( http://www.melissahie.com/ ) that you requested is using MOTOOLS for the transition effects. Check this david walsh link to understand it better as it contains an example as well http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/fx.explode.php.

For the Page slide efect you can aso check this link http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/

Let me know if you still missing something :)

**LATEST EDIT-**

FOR DIAGONAL EFFECT CHECK THIS LINK--

http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: here is the link http://www.melissahie.com/ when you click on the word website you will see the transition

Comment: how about the diagonal effect any example for it?

Comment: I tried your sample page looks good. So if I want it to be separate page itself is that possible because now I notice is all in same page rite?

Comment: @user837306 yeah you can even do this, using jquery load ..and let me know if you are finally satisfied with my answer ..long wait ;)

Comment: yes I am satisfied with your answer only not quite sure with your jquery load is it to load the other page is it so must I put in this function $('a.panel').click(function () {? The sample is more on div manipulation rite.

Comment: @user837306 yes its more abt div but as you mentioned "a simple few pages html link" i think it now wont be much hard to apply..if u face any problem while designing let me know...ready to help u :)

Comment: I must do some work in this function $('a.panel').click(function () { am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

These guys have some great code for doing page transitions: http://tympanus.net/codrops/

eg: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlitSlider/